# libGDX : Paint And Remove Color From Actor with touchDragged

Tags: java, libgdx

I created two-dimensional array of `Button` actor, then I added `new ClickListener() { 
touchDragged }` as the following code:

```
buttons = new Button[3][3];

for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < buttons[0].length; col++) {

buttons[row][col] = new Button(drawable);

buttons[row][col].addListener(new ClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                    for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
                        for (int col = 0; col < buttons[0].length; col++) {
                            if (buttons[row][col].isOver()) {
                                buttons[row][col].setColor(Color.GREEN);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
   }
}
```

the code inside `touchDragged` method if the buttons `isOver` the buttons colored `GREEN` (it works fine) as shown in image [image]

Now, How can I remove `Color.GREEN` i.e. (`Color.WHITE`) from buttons in the same calling `touchDragged` method, I mean undo `GREEN` to `WHITE` if the `isOver()` still `true`??

this image clear my question : [image]

like Alphabetty Game from king company, if you know it :).

Sorry, For bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create `List` :

```
private List<Integer> list;

// In create OR show Method 
list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

2- Create this line code (as ID for `buttons[row][col]`):

```
buttons[row][col].setName("" + id++);
```

3- Write this code inside your `touchDragged` .. after your loop:

```
if (buttons[row][col].isOver()) {
    try {
        if (list.contains(Integer.parseInt(buttons[row][col].getName()))) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(buttons[row][col].getName()) == list.get(list.size() - 2)) {
                stage.getRoot().findActor("" + list.get(list.size() - 1)).setColor(Color.WHITE);
                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            }
        } else {
            buttons[row][col].setColor(Color.GREEN);
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(buttons[row][col].getName()));
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getClass());
      }
}
```

4- See the answer in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7SdM2VgGbs)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an if statement to check which colour the square is. If it is white, colour it green and vice versa.

I have something similar and for some reason you can't directly compare colours in an if statement, however changing them to an rgb int value solves this. You can choose from the various rgb options such as rgba8888 or argb8888 etc, choose one which will suit your needs. The simplest one would just be rgb888. It is a static method in the colour class, pass it a colour it will return an int.

```
if(Color.rgb888(button[row][col].getColor()) == Color.rgb888(Color.Green()))
    {
        button[row][col].setColor(Color.White());
    }
```

Comment: I said in my question (in the same time for calling touchDragged method), I mean `isOver()` still true.

Comment: Oh right, I get what you mean, I thought my answer was a bit too simple. Maybe create an array for all of the squares numbered 1-9. Where the player puts finger down that is first in array, next box in next in array and so on. If the player goes into a box that is already in the array then change it to white. You could find the square you were in last, it would be the last non 0 value in array and if you re enter it, set the square you just left to white. Hopefully, that makes sense.

Comment: On my phone just now, I'll get it when I get to my computer later

Comment: Cool,  and I will try again.

Comment: Oh, unbelievable. I Solved it `EssEllDee`. Yaaaa, Cool Coool. See My code Answer. `EssEllDee` Provide me your code too, maybe your code is better than my code.

Comment: Your code is along the same lines as what I was thinking, no need for mine, nice job.

Comment: Cool.  Thanx for ur answer and reply on my question.