# libGDX : touchDragged doesn't work on android device

Tags: java, libgdx

Why `touchDragged` methd work only on Desktop, doesn't work on android device ?

```
buttons[row][col].addListener(new DragListener() {
        @Override
        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < buttons[0].length; col++) {
                    if (buttons[row][col].isOver()) {
                       buttons[row][col].setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                }
            }
       }
});
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Comment: Did you return true for the touch down event?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but I noticed you can simplify this by creating a single listener that is shared by all images in your array. Within the listener,  the current image is the event's actor. Then you won't have to search the whole array over and over.

Comment: @Johnathon Havens. Ya.

Comment: @Tenfour04. More clear or code plz. And I want to understand why this works on `Desktop`  not `Android`

Comment: Your code also works on desktop only !!! ... WHAT IS THE PROBLEM ??

Comment: Can you show your `image.isOver()` method? Is an `image` a custom Actor subclass of yours?

Comment: Change `touchDragged` to simply `drag`. I just noticed that you're overriding a critical method for how DragListener works. You're supposed to override the `drag` method instead.

Comment: `DragListener sharedListener = new DragListener(){public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {event.getTarget().setColor(Color.GREEN);}; for (Image item : image) item.addListener(sharedListener);`

Comment: Sorry I used `Button`, not Image sorry again.

Comment: I test `touchDragged` with toast message on Android it works fine.

Comment: ok, I will test `drag` method

Comment: I edited my question to buttons.

Comment: @Tenfour04 `drag` method also doesn't work on android !!

Comment: Are you still using isOver? That method returns whether the mouse pointer is hovering over the button so it will always be false on Android.

Comment: Ya. now I got it. `isOver()` method is false on Android. Now, what is method instead of `isOver()`

Comment: You can't really be 'over' anything in android, you have to rethink it for android. You will have to check if the x and y value received by the drag event are within the buttons boundaries.

Comment: Plz, see this [video] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7SdM2VgGbs) 
I want to make this on android. HOW ?

Comment: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878595/libgdx-paint-and-remove-color-from-actor-with-touchdragged)

Comment: Ya, you are alright. the best way to make this on Android is checking buttons boundaries. `Vector2 position = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(x, y));
  for (Button item : buttons) {
   if (position.x > item.getX() && position.x <= item.getX() + item.getWidth() && 
    position.y > item.getY() && position.y <= item.getY() + item.getHeight())
    item.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  }`

Comment: THANX A LOT @Johnathon Havens ;)